# Java method that prints the top 20% of values from a sorted copy of an array

Tags: java, arrays, percentage, percentile

This is the code I have so far.  I'm not even sure I created the copied sorted array correctly.  The whole 80%-percentile think confuses me so I have no idea how to finish this code.  Any ideas would be really helpful.

```
public static int top_20(int[]arr, int size){
     Arrays.sort(arr);
     int[] sorted = new int[size];
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
         sorted[i] = arr[i];
     }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < size * 20 / 100; i++){` seems pretty logical. Change it to 20 or 80; It's not clear what one you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to setup the `for` cycle correctly. In case of top 20% it would be something like

```
for (int i = (int) (size * 0.8); i < size; i++)
```

You can also use `arr.length` to determine the size of an array. The first part `size * 0.8` is to determine, where to start, `(int)` cuts off the decimal part, in order to get `int`, that can be used as an index. Finally, you want to go up to `size`, (or `arr.length` for that matter). This will print out the top 20% elements of the array, with some minor inaccuracies introduced by the rounding.

Answer (score 0):

start from scratch.  break down the problem statement into smaller pieces, and solve them.

1. how do you compute a percentage?  apply that knowledge to compute how many is 20% of the array.
2. given that number, what range of array indices do you need?
3. how do you print a number?
4. how do you print a series of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] top_20(int[] arr){
     Arrays.sort(arr);

     int size = (int)(arr.length * 0.2); // size is 20% of array
     int start = (int)(arr.length * 0.8); // start at the 80th percentile

     int[] top20 = new int[size + 1];

     for(int i = start; i < arr.length; i++){
         top20[i - start] = arr[i];
     }

     return top20;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] x = {92,92,93,94,98,72,75,79,80}; // maybe a class' marks

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(top_20(x))); // [94, 98]
}
```